# Installing Lua socket library

Tags: sockets, lua, luasocket

Either I'm overtired or blind. I want to learn networking with Lua and therefore I have to install the `socket` lib, so I can require it easily, but I don't know, which files I should "require". The example says:

```
local socket = require("socket")
```

but as I said, I don't know which files I should include, if I use `socket.lua` it doesn't work and I get: `No files found`.

I got the lib from here: [Lua socket download](http://files.luaforge.net/releases/luasocket/luasocket/luasocket-2.0.2)

Or, is there another way to install the socket lib?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the [installation instructions?](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/installation.html)

Comment: maybe the `# luarocks install luasocket` command can help you.

Answer (score 14):

When you load a module with `require` Lua uses the package paths to determine where to look for the module. Have a look at the [Modules](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.3) section of the Lua manual. Specifically, the section on `package.path` and `package.cpath`.

> package.path: The path used by require to search for a Lua loader (.lua modules)
>   package.cpath: The path used by require to search for a C loader (.so/.dll modules)

You can check what the current paths are:

```
print(package.path..'\n'..package.cpath)
```

If you install LuaSocket into a location within your current package paths Lua should be able to locate and load it.

Alternatively, you can modify the package paths before calling `require`. For example, if you create a folder for your project and extract the LuaSocket library to a sub-folder called `libs` within your project folder:

```
Project
|
> libs
     |
     > lua
         |
         > socket         
     > socket
     > mime
```

You can set the package paths relative to your project before you `require` the socket library (substitute `/?.dll` for `/?.so` on Linux):

```
package.path = package.path..';./libs/lua/?.lua'
package.cpath = package.cpath..';./libs/socket/?.dll;./libs/mime/?.dll'
local socket = require 'socket'
```

Answer (score 2):

use this command on your linux system :

```
#luarocks install luasocket
```

the use the next command to see the paths CONFIGURATION

```
#luarocks
```

You need to use default linux account (see: CONFIGURATION) :

```
$lua 
> socket = require ("socket")
```

or use this:

```
> socket = require 'socket'
```