# "require" doesn't work with another directory, but the path is correct

Tags: lua, directory, require

```
a = ";E:\\Code\\Lua\\FakeMagic\\testingarea\\test\\libs\\?.dll"
package.path = package.path .. a
midi = require "luamidi"
```

I got:

```
E:\Soft\lua\5.1\lua.exe: error loading module 'luamidi' from file 'E:\Code\Lua\FakeMagic\testingarea\test\libs\luamidi.dll':
        E:\Code\Lua\FakeMagic\testingarea\test\libs\luamidi.dll:1: '=' expected near 'Р'
stack traceback:
        [C]: ?
        [C]: in function 'require'
        E:\Code\Lua\FakeMagic\testingarea\test\midi.lua:2: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

But when luamidi.dll at the same directory with the lua file all is ok.
P.S The path is correct.

Comment: Use `package.cpath` for loading shared libraries. See the [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.cpath)

Comment: Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356709/installing-lua-socket-library/10358900#10358900) might be of some help.

Comment: @Adam yep, that's work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lua's path list for DLL/SO files is different from its path list for .lua scripts. The DLL/SO path list is stored in `package.cpath`.